# What does wrapping configuration information behind thin API mean?

Tags: javascript, configuration

On reading `Pragmatic Programmer`, the authors recommend that we wrap configuration information behind a thin API as it decouples the details of the representation of the configuration.

Quote from the book about Configuration.

> Commonly, this data structure is made global, the thinking being that this makes it easier for any part of the code to get to the values it holds.
> We prefer that you don't do that. Instead wrap the configuration information behind a (thin) API. This decouples your code from the details of the representation of the configuration.

I am not sure how that decouples the details of the representation of the configuration. For example, If I have a javascript object that stores a configuration value, the client could access the configuration value via `object.<someConfigKey>`. Wouldn't wrapping this configuration value inside an object result in the client calling something like `config.<getSomeConfigKey>()` ?

Since configuration objects are usually represented as a data structure (I.e `json` like), how does wrapping configuration information behind a thin API result in decoupling ?